# Apply conjugation to real array (Fortran)

Tags: arrays, fortran, complex-numbers, intel-fortran

In Fortran, I have an 1D array of type real, `real :: work(2*N)`, which represents `N` complex numbers. I don't have any impact of the declaration of the array.

Later I need to apply a complex conjugation on `work`. However, `conjg(work(:))` does not work since it is of type real.

Is there a efficient way to convince the compiler to apply the `conjg` to my array?

Comment: Or something like `work(2::2) = -1*work(2::2)` ?  Untried, untested, no Fortran on this machine.

Comment: even more tersely, `work(2::2)=-work(2::2)`  (tested..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is already in the comment by HighPerformanceMark, just multiply the elements representing the imaginary part by -1.

You can also use `equivalence` between a real array and a complex array. It will be just one array but viewed as both real and complex. Maybe not strictly standard conforming (not sure) but working as long as `N` is constant.

The equivalence is used as:

```
real :: work(2*N)
complex :: cwork(N)

!both work and cwork point to the same data
equivalence (work, cwork)

work = some_initial_value

!this conjugates work at the same time as cwork because they are just different names for the same array
cwork = conjg(cwork)
```

Comment: I believe `equivalence` is absolutely standards conforming, so long as the complex array is declared exactly half the length of the real one.  By some quick testing `conjg`/`equivalence` is a good bit faster than the slice operation. (Maybe you should show an example )

Answer (score 2):

Use a complex variable, `COMPLEX :: temp(N)` and apply the conjugation to that. You can then dissect the real and complex parts and put them back into your work array by using `REAL(temp)` and `AIMAG(temp)`.
Probably it is better to make your `work` a complex type from the outset though.